# How to monitor an external process (simplest approach)

Tags: c#, windows-10, monitoring

I have a csharp app running in my customer's server. The app is a Windows Service.
I want to be able to tell if app is running, if it is stopped and lastly I want to be able to restart it. Everthing must be done from a web client app.

Because access from external networks to this machine is restricted by my customer, I was thinking about implementing an "Agent Client", which will be just another Windows Service running locally and that could execute the "restart" and "stop" commands. It would be pulling an external "Agent Server" to find out if commands need to be executed.

What do you think about this? Any better ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you can't access into the server, can it access out?  Could it send status updates via HTTP to a webserver.  It could also send a heartbeat every xx minutes.  You could also then leave commands for it to execute on the webserver, and the next time it connects it retrieves these commands and executes them.  There would be a delay, but it could work.

Comment: Yes, it can access out.